# ¿Cómo generar una ruta que pase por varios puntos en Gmap C#?

Tags: c#, google-maps, rutas

Hola estoy realizando un generador de ruta de entrega, la información se encuentra en una base de dato que se encuentra en el DatagridView2, se trata de tener varios puntos de entrega y trazar una ruta que pase por cada uno.
sin embargo empiezo en esto de programar y no conozco mucho del tema de gmap, ya he intentado varias formas sin embargo no he logrado obtener un resultado.

Este es el código sobre el que estoy trabajando:

```
private void btn_comollegar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    GMapOverlay ruta = new GMapOverlay("capa de ruta");
    GMapOverlay caparutas = new GMapOverlay("capa de la ruta");
    List<PointLatLng> guia = new List<PointLatLng>();
    // creamos las variables para almacenar los datos
    double lat, lng;
    // tomamos los datos del grid
    for (int filas = 0; filas < DataGridView2.Rows.Count; filas++){
        lat = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[2].Value);
        lng = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[3].Value);
        guia.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, lng));
        inicio = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
        final = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
    }
    GDirections direccion;                                            
    var rutasdireccion = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out direccion, inicio, final, false, false, false, false, false);    
    GMapRoute rutaobtenida = new GMapRoute(direccion.Route, "Ruta Ubicación");
    caparutas.Routes.Add(rutaobtenida);
    gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(caparutas);
    // para actualizar
    //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom + 1;
    //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom - 1;
    gMapControl1.UpdateRouteLocalPosition(rutaobtenida); 
}
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme un poco, de ante mano gracias.

He actualizado el código y he estado trabajando en ello actual mente lo tengo como:

```
        MapRoute rutasdireccion;
        GMapRoute rutaobtenida;
        GMapOverlay caparutas;
                    // creamos las variables para almacenar los datos
                    double lat, lng;
        // tomamos los datos del grid
        for (int filas = 0; filas < DataGridView2.Rows.Count-1; filas++)
        {

                lat = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[2].Value);
                lng = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[3].Value);

                puntos.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, lng));

                rutasdireccion = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(puntos[filas], puntos[filas+1], true, false, 10);
                rutaobtenida = new GMapRoute(rutasdireccion.Points, "Ruta Ubicación");
              caparutas  = new GMapOverlay("capa de la ruta");
                caparutas.Routes.Add(rutaobtenida);
                gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(caparutas);
                // para actualizar
                //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom + 1;
                //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom - 1;
                gMapControl1.UpdateRouteLocalPosition(rutaobtenida);

        }
```

Sin embargo ahora me marca el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas,

En la última versión de tu código se produce un error ya que en la primera iteración del bucle `for`solo has añadido un elemento a `puntos` por lo tanto en esa primera iteración no puedes consultar dos puntos para añadirlos a tu `caparutas`. Para no cambiar muchísimo el código, lo que puedes hacer es no ejecutar esa parte en la primera iteración del bucle.

Te dejo como quedaría el código:

```
    MapRoute rutasdireccion;
    GMapRoute rutaobtenida;
    GMapOverlay caparutas;
    // creamos las variables para almacenar los datos
    double lat, lng;
    // tomamos los datos del grid
    for (int filas = 0; filas < DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; filas++)
    {

        lat = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[2].Value);
        lng = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView2.Rows[filas].Cells[3].Value);

        //En este apartado añades un punto a tu lista
        puntos.Add(new PointLatLng(lat, lng));

        //Si queremos utilizar 2 elementos de la lista puntos debemos estar seguros de que existen, al menos,
        //esos 2 elementos, es decir en la primera iteración del bucle no debo realizar esta parte
        if (puntos.Count() >= 2)
        {
            rutasdireccion =
                GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(puntos[filas], puntos[filas + 1], true, false, 10);
            rutaobtenida = new GMapRoute(rutasdireccion.Points, "Ruta Ubicación");
            caparutas = new GMapOverlay("capa de la ruta");
            caparutas.Routes.Add(rutaobtenida);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(caparutas);
            // para actualizar
            //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom + 1;
            //gMapControl1.Zoom = gMapControl1.Zoom - 1;
            gMapControl1.UpdateRouteLocalPosition(rutaobtenida);
        }

    }
```

De esta forma recorrerías todos los elementos que deseas sin salirte del rango.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: muchas gracias ElGerar sin embargo al realizar esto me marca que el índice se encuentra fuera del intervalo o el valor es nulo en:                        if (puntos[filas+1] != null)

Comment: @GSA esta respuesta soluciono el problema? si no lo soluciono, no debe ser aceptada. Si lo soluciono, aclara tu comentario.

Comment: @gbianchi entendido, si ayudó la respuesta, sin embargo surgió la problemática que plantee en el comentario: en dónde me marca el error en: if (puntos[filas+1] != null)...

Comment: Porque vas a buscar la fila siguiente dentro del for?

Comment: Es que guia sólo está inicializada y en la primera pasada no le has metido valores

Comment: Y es q ese if no parece necesario no ?

Comment: @gbianchi lo de fila+1, lo tenía dentro del if esto era para determinar si existía más datos en el DataGridView2, sin embargo ElGerar tiene razón no es necesario teniendo el ciclo for.

Comment: @ElGerar el código lo he actualizado, por lo que guia no lo he utilizado más

Comment: El error está claro metes un punto en `puntos` e intentas acceder a dos , cosa q no existe.

Comment: @GSA no debes ir editando la pregunta con lo que te dan como respuesta. Si la respuesta que te dieron sirvio, tenes que aceptarla y hacer una pregunta nueva si tenes otra duda. Porque si no, las respuestas quedan invalidas porque la pregunta cambio y no sirven. Si tenes alguna duda que no se pueda resolver en los comentarios, hace una nueva pregunta, e indica como referencia esta.

Comment: GSA como dice @gbianchi voy a contestarte al estado actual de tu pregunta ya que realmente son errores de depuración. Si aun así no consigues que te la lógica te funcione te recomiendo abrir una nueva pregunta con el código actualizado y añadiendo las entradas y las salidas esperadas de ese código. Un saludo y ahora edito mi respuesta para corregir los errores detectados en tu última actualización.

Comment: entendido apenas empiezo a utilizar la pagina gbiachi, @ElGerar me volvía a salir el error en getroute( puntos[fila]...por lo que cambie el codigo para que tomara el valor de la fila 0 y fila 1 quedó->   rutasdireccion = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(puntos[filas-1], puntos[filas], false, false, 15);, esto para que tome el punto anterior ya que como me decías se salta el primer punto, sin embargo en la siguiente línea, me dice que rutasdireccion se encuentra como nulo

Comment: @GSA Has usado mi modificación y no te funcionaba? (Antes de este último cambio que has hecho me refiero)

Comment: @ElGerar si lo he utilizado y me decía que tenia que estar dentro del campo por eso he modificado a filas -1 para que tomara el primer valor y el valor en el que se encuentra el ciclo for: pero ahora me dice que estos valores se encuentran como nul

Comment: @ElGerar hola he revisado y al parecer .GetRoute ya no está disponible por lo que he utilizado    GDirections direccion;
                  var rutasdireccion = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out direccion, puntos[filas-1], puntos[filas], true, false, false, false, false); ya me traza una ruta sin embargo, solo me marca 2 de 3 puntos que tengo

Comment: @ElGerar ya logre resolver el problema muchas gracias por la ayuda